# diagonal asymptotes of a hyperbola

Tags: asymptotics

How do I calculate the asymptotes of the hyperbola
$$y=\frac{2x(x+2)}{x-3}
$$
I know the horizontal asymptotes, but the problem is what is the diagonal asymptote?

Comment: Hint: when is the right-hand-side expression defined? What happens close to that $x$-value?

Comment: Hint : use the long division (by decreasing powers)